# No output for multiple queries in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

We dynamically generate a sql file which contains one big **insert** query. This file will be run periodically from a PHP app with the following command:

```
mysql --force  -u foo -pbar demo < demo-file.sql
```

There was no output from the command except when an error happened as the content of the file was only one **insert** command. Now we decided to change the file that it will contain multiple **insert** queries instead of one big query. Since then the output of the command is

```
0
0
0
```

Our PHP app fails because it assumes now that there is an error happening because the output is not empty. So my question is, can I write an sql file that there is no output generated with multiple queries? I try not to touch the PHP app.

I know there are better designs but the code is historically grown :-)

*[UPDATE 1]*

Basically the app does

```
$response = shell_exec('mysql --force  -u foo -pbar demo < demo-file.sql');
if (empty($response)) {
  echo 'OK';
} else {
  echo 'error: '.$response;
}
```

*[UPDATE 2]*
The sql file contains something like

```
insert into;
select sleep(0);
insert into;
select sleep(0);
insert into;
select sleep(0);
```

Comment: Nothing besides inserts in the file?

Comment: could you direct the output to >> /dev/null

Comment: Do the inserts work? May be it is indicating an error.

Comment: Yes, basically insert into on duplicate update.

Comment: Yes they work, as the output is 0. It is a client server app where I try to avoid to change the client as they are multiple clients with one server, simplified said.

Comment: The PHP app assumes when there is output that something went wrong.

Comment: @Laoneo: Change the assumption of your php app?

Comment: @dognose it is part of a client server architecture where the PHP app is the client getting the sql file from the server in simple words explained.

Comment: @dognose yes - this seems to be the most clean solution (in this case).

Comment: I can't repeat the problem, running your exact command (with changed user/pass) with multiple inserts gives no output for me.

Comment: Do you have an insert on duplicate update? Perhaps I should mention that I add a select sleep(2); between the statements.

Answer (score 0):

Those zeros come from the sleep lines. Get rid of them, you don't need them.

Also, for performance sake, if you are using a schema that supports transactions, you should add:

```
START TRANSACTION
INSERT...
INSERT...
INSERT...
...
COMMIT
```

Comment: I don't want 0 as output. I want no output if all went fine, only in error cases.

Comment: Ah, well then just make the shell script do the sum and output nothing if the sum is 0.

Comment: I try not to change the behavior of the PHP app (shell script).

Comment: How is PHP calling the mysql command you've listed? Are you willing to change that line? If so you can write a bash script (not changing the php) and the only line you need to change is what the php script calls.

Comment: Are you willing to change toe contents of the shell_exec statement?

Comment: AS I mentioned in the question I try to avoid that.

Comment: Updated my answer. Get rid of the sleep lines and you'll have no output.

Comment: The file is over 50 mb big which we run several times at the same time which can crash the server.

Comment: This shouldn't be an issue with InnoDB, so I'm guessing you're runnign Myisam. Change your inserts to INSERT DELAYED and you can run a ton at once and things will not crash.

Comment: Didn't know that but "As of MySQL 5.6.6, INSERT DELAYED is deprecated, and will be removed in a future release. Use INSERT (without DELAYED) instead."

Comment: What is your mysql version? And are you using MyISAM or InnoDB?

Comment: InnoDB and 5.5 on ubuntu.

Comment: Okau, if you're running InnoDB, then scratch INSERT DELAYED that's more of a hack to deal with the shortcomings of MyISAM. InnoDB should be able to handle multiple simultaneous 50MB inserts with no issue. Try it with transactions like it is shown in my answer and see if you have an issue.